# C++ Placing words into stacks based on even or odd numbers

Tags: c++, file, sorting, stack, readfile

I am making a program that gives a random movie to the user based on what number they enter. Each movie has a number associated with it, so there should be two stacks, one for even and one for odd. The way the program will work at the end is the user enters a number, and if it is odd they will get a movie from the pool of odd numbers.
This is what my input.txt looks like:

> 1. DC's Legends of Tomorrow
> 2. Ice Age 5: Collision Course
> 3. Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children
> 4. Forbidden Empire
> 5. The Zero Theorem
> 6. X-Men: Days of Future Past
> 7. Jupiter Ascending
> 8. The Mortal Instruments: City Of Bones
> 9. The Age of Adaline
> 10. Melancholia

I want to split these movies into those two stacks, so stack_odd would have DC's Legends, Miss Peregrine's, The Zero Theorem, etc.

I am unsure how to go about splitting these into the stacks however.
This is what I do to open the file.

```
lass CReadFile {
    protected:
            Stack<string> stack_even;
            Stack<string> stack_odd;
            bool isblank(const std::string& s)
            {    //True if s is empty or only contains space and/or TABs.
                return s.find_first_not_of(" \t")==std::string::npos;
            }
            void readFile (string filename)
            {   ifstream file(filename);
                string line;
                // file opened?
                if (! file) {
                    cerr << "can't open input file \"" << filename << "\""<< endl;
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                
                file.close();
            }
```

To do the stack would I go:

```
int a;
while(file >> a){
    if(a % 2 == 0){
        stack_even.push(a);
    }else{
        stack_odd.push(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a count variable and check for even or odd occurance by incrementing count in each iteration, refer code below:

```
string a;
int count = 0
while (getline (file, a)){
    if(count % 2 == 0){
        stack_even.push(a);
    }else{
        stack_odd.push(a);
    }
    count ++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but when trying this it put everything into stack_even and stack_odd ended up empty

Comment: Psycho Bunnies it shall work . Are you incrementing count => count ++; You must have missed something from above.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. It might be my placement? I put it right after the if statement in readFile

Comment: Are you new to C/C++ programing? I think you should go through some tutorials and do your basics strong.

Comment: I am, I am currently taking a C++ class online but it has been very difficult. Thank you for trying to help me, I appreciate it.